# How I have here to use the lock condition?

Tags: java, multithreading

here I have a task that I have to use locks and condiitons. In the methods sum() and randomSwap() are the task which I have to complete. So there is enumerated what I have to do. First the class and the task in the methods without my Editings:

```
public class LockedDataObject extends DataObject {

    /** Number of current readers */
    int noReaders;

     /** True, if writer is currently waiting or writing */
    boolean writer;

    /**
     * Condition variable to put to sleep or wake up the recorder.
     */
    Condition condWrite;

    /** Condition variable for putting readers to sleep or waking them up */.
    Condition condRead;

   /**
     * Lock to protect all upper variables. Before accessing any of the
     * variables is accessed, this lock may need to be acquired. The
     * lock should *only be acquired if it is absolutely necessary for correct * execution.
     * execution. This is with a changing access
     * only if other threads can read or write the corresponding variable * at the same 
     *time.
     * can read or write the corresponding variable at the same time. In the case of a 
     *reading access
     * the lock should not be acquired if other threads can only read * the variable at the 
     *same time, but not write it.
     * read, but not write, access to the corresponding variable at the same time.
     * at the same time.
     */

    ReentrantLock lock;

    public LockedDataObject() {
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.condRead = lock.newCondition();
        this.condWrite = lock.newCondition();
        this.noReaders = 0;
        this.writer = false;
    }

    public int sum() {
        // Note the correct use of the lock variable throughout.
        // "lock". Acquire the lock only if it is absolutely necessary.

        // 1. as long as a writer is waiting or writing, sleep.

        // 2. increase the number of readers by 1.


        // 3. sum up
        int sum = super.sum();

        // 4. decrease the number of readers and, if necessary, wake up the writers.
        
        // 5. return the total
        return sum;
    }

    public void randomSwap() {
        // Note the correct use of the lock variable throughout.
        // "lock". Acquire the lock only if absolutely necessary.

        // 1. indicate that a writer is waiting.

        // 2. put to sleep as long as at least one reader is still active.

        // 3. swap elements
        super.randomSwap();

        // 4. indicate that no writer is waiting/writing anymore and
        // wake up readers if necessary.
    }
}
```

Now my result:

```
   public int sum() {
        // Note the correct use of the lock variable throughout.
        // "lock". Acquire the lock only if it is absolutely necessary.

        // 1. as long as a writer is waiting or writing, sleep.
        while(writer==true) {
            lock.lock();
        }
        // 2. increase the number of readers by 1.
        noReaders=noReaders+1;

        // 3. sum up
        int sum = super.sum();

        // 4. decrease the number of readers and, if necessary, wake up the writers.
        noReaders=noReaders-1;
        try {
            condWrite.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // 5. return the total
        return sum;
    }

    public void randomSwap() {
        // Note the correct use of the lock variable throughout.
        // "lock". Acquire the lock only if absolutely necessary.

        // 1. show/indicate that a writer is waiting.
        
        //Here I dont now what they want with show that a Writer ist waiting...
        
        // 2. put to sleep as long as at least one reader is still active.
        while(writer) {
            lock.lock();
        }
        // 3. swap elements
        super.randomSwap();

        // 4. indicate that no writer is waiting/writing anymore and
        // wake up readers if necessary.
        if(writer==false) {
            try {
                condWrite.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Could someone check, if its correct what I made? Thank you all for the help

Comment: For most uses of `ReentrantLock` I've used (typically with a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`), it would follow the form of `try { lock.lock(); /* ...code... */ } finally { lock.unlock(); }`

Comment: Thank you, but I have the variable writer which says:     /** True, if writer is currently waiting or writing */. An the first task says:         // 1. as long as a writer is waiting or writing, sleep. So normally I have to use this variabel and not a try block or?

Comment: Calling `#lock` will block until the lock is available already (no need for the while loop). Being a reentrant lock means that if your current thread owns the lock already (from a previous `#lock` call), then you won't block yourself by calling it again. The reason to use a `try...finally` block is so that when you have finished with the lock, you can ensure that the `#unlock` is called accordingly in _any_ situation (including erroneous ones or returns)

Comment: Thank you but when i dont need the while loop, what i make with the variable wirter?

Comment: You honestly do not need the `writer` variable (outside of the exercise instructions), as `Lock#tryLock` would attempt acquiring the lock, returning `false` if it is already locked/unavailable. When code after a `Lock#lock` call starts to execute, you are effectively the only thread executing it, and can adjust things like `writer = true` and `noReaders++;`

Comment: @Rogue well, to support multiple readers when using `ReentrantLock`, you have to release the lock for the actual operation (`sum()`), which implies that you have to maintain the state on your own, hence need `noReaders` and `writer`. Advanced programmers would probably fold them into one variable, but that’s outside the scope of this task, obviously.